# Change background color of facebook login button for ios

Tags: ios, swift

I am using facebook sdk for facebook login but I am unable to customize facebook button. Is there any way I can subclass my button as FBSDKLoginButton and change the background color as my need.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will simplify this:

1- make the facebook button but dont show it (don't addsubView the facebook page)

2- make a UIButton of your own, customize it the way you want and display it instead iof the faecbook button

3- onClick of your button fake the touch of the hidden facebook button `[facebookbutton sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own UIButton and connect with login function.

Try to check the link below, FBSDK docs.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#custom-login-button

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift**

1. Make your own design UIButton.
2. Create button action on your viewcontroller class.
3. Add the following line inside button action,

   loginButtonFacebook.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)